# My element doesnt appear when ng-show="true"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a little problem, I want my element to show up when my window width become less than 850 px , so this is my function ( verification in every 0.2s ) :

```
 $scope.existence = false;
 $scope.changeEtat = $interval(function () {
    var number = window.innerWidth
    if (number > 853) {
        $scope.existence = false
    } else {
        $scope.existence = true
    }
}, 200)
```

and here is my Html code :

```
<ul>
    <li id="menu-icon" ng-show="{{existence}}">
        <img src="assets/images/menu-icon.jpg">
    </li>
    <li><br><a href="">FILM STREAMING</a></li>
    <li><br><a href="">SERIE STREAMING</a></li>
    <li id="short"><br><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
    <li id="short"><br><a href="">DMCA</a></li>
    <li><br><a href="">CONTACTER-NOUS</a></li>
</ul>
```

In my inspector, I can see that the ng-show value changes when the window width changes but the element don't appear at all.

Thanks you for your help

Comment: try without curly brackets -  ng-show="existence"

Comment: mike : yes, it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `interpolation` in `ngShow` directive.

```
<ul>
    <li id="menu-icon" ng-show="existence"><img src="assets/images/menu-icon.jpg"></li>
    <li><br><a href="">FILM STREAMING</a></li>
    <li><br><a href="">SERIE STREAMING</a></li>
    <li id="short"><br><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
    <li id="short"><br><a href="">DMCA</a></li>
    <li><br><a href="">CONTACTER-NOUS</a></li>
</ul>
```

> The ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute.

```
<div ng-show="myValue"></div>
```

[**Documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)